# does not known my file inside raw folder

Tags: android, android-studio

someone know why my commands.json file inside raw folder is not known ?

[image]

I got `cannot resolve symbole 'commands '`
I have a few flavours and inside raw folder of each flavor, I have overrode  my commands.json file.

Comment: you can put this file in assets folder.

Comment: Thank you but I want to solve this problem and find what is my mistake??

Comment: why downvote???

Comment: i didn't downvoted

Comment: seems some one like get downvote to people..my qustion was clear!! why downvote!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier(         "commands",          "raw",  getPackageName()));
//                                                                             FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION          YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME
```

instead of this

```
InputStream ins = cx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.commands);
```